# Swagger-client error when attempting to run React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swagger

Let me begin that this is an older React project and I am not the most well-versed in React. After some days of trying solutions nothing resolves the issue and I personally couldn't find any other error logs. Does anything here jump out at you all?

I have attempted to run in Administrator mode, removing the node_modules folder,

> NPM Version: 10.1.0 | Node Version: v20.9.0

> Module not found: Can't resolve
> '@swagger-api/apidom-reference/configuration/empty' in
> '[PATH]\project\node_modules\swagger-client\es\execute'
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
> lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

```
{
      "name": "[PROJECT]",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
"sass": "latest",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
"react-color": "^2.18.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-draggable": "^4.4.3",
"react-dynamic-modal": "^1.1.1",
"react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
"react-is": "^16.13.1",
"react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"styled-components": "^5.1.1",
"swagger-client": "^3.10.12"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "build:dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts build",
        "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts build"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.10.4",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
        "flow": "^0.2.3",
        "flow-bin": "^0.132.0",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "yarn-check": "^0.0.3"
      },
      "description": "[PROJECT]",
      "main": "index.js",
      "repository": "[REPO]",
      "author": "[PROCESS]",
      "license": "[REPO]"
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned that you have tried to delete node_modules but have you tried to delete node_modules, run npm install and then run npm cache clean?

Comment: Alapaah, thanks! I have done just that. The npm cache clean responds with:

"As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were using version `^3.10.12` of the package `swagger-client`, try using version `3.18.5` instead (at the time of writing, `^3.10.12` will install `3.23.1`).

Version `3.19.0` changed some stuff (and introduced `@swagger-api/apidom-reference`, which is where you get an error) so maybe try before that big change.

Comment: Oh wow, that did do it. Thanks! has to be something in there.